# Como versionar um projeto whitelabel?

Tags: git

Bom dia pessoal, eu trabalho com git já faz um tempinho, mas me deparei com um problema que não consegui achar uma solução que funcione.
Eu tenho um projeto "white label", que seria mais ou menos assim:
Tem um branch "principal" onde está praticamente todo o código do projeto, e tenho outros branches "clientes" que são personalizados com cores, logo, nome e url da api de cada um.
Onde me enrosquei é que não sei como gerenciar as atualizções no código sem dar merge e sobrescrever as configurações de cada um dos branches "clientes".

Alguém tem alguma dica para facilitar essa integração, sem ter que ficar replicando manualmente em cada branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim isso é possível definindo uma estratégia para o arquivo ou uma pasta.

Por exemplo, imagine que no seu projeto exista um logo do cliente que você quer preservar no merge, e que está no caminho:  "images/logo.png"

Você pode criar um atributo para esse arquivo e definir a estratégia de merge. 
Para isso, crie um arquivo `.gitattributes` na estrutura do seu projeto, e inclua o seguinte conteúdo:

`/images/logo.png  merge=ours`

Isso diz ao git que, ao fazer o merge, deve manter a sua versão (ours).
Deve fazer isso em todas as branchs que contenham o mesmo arquivo. Isso seria como se o merge fosse manual e escolhe a sua versão.

Quando for fazer o merge, informe que vai usar essa estratégia com o comando `git config merge.ours.driver true`.
Se estiver usando alguma IDE para executar os comandos, execute uma vez `git config --global merge.ours.driver true` e isso ficará padrão e pode fazer merge/rebase tranquilamente pela IDE.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou pesquisar mais sobre o gitattributes!